# Can I use my iPad to as a speaker for my laptop?

Tags: laptop, bluetooth, speakers, ipad

My laptop sound card is not working and I will use ipad's speaker for my laptop with bluetooth pair. For example when I'll watch movie on my laptop, its sound play with my ipad until I fixed my laptop sound card.

How can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) to do this via your wireless network. Run *Airfoil Speakers Touch* on the iPad, and the *Airfoil* application on your Windows or Mac OS X computer.

Comment: I try but the sound not play from the application,I don't have sound card in my laptop.

Comment: Can I play sound from iPad while I don't have any sound card on my laptop? @DanielBeck

Comment: @Navid_gh What kind of laptop doesn't have any sound? Chances are Airfoil won't work because the applications don't even start playing.

Comment: My laptop ( XPS L501X ) sound card is not available, I think it's broken.My Kmplayer started and play video and its sync with ipad and ipad showed receiving sound data from kmplayer but iPad don't play the movie sound. @DanielBeck

Comment: @Navid_gh Did you mute your iPad's speakers? Are you able to play sound in other apps?

Comment: No, I didn't. Yes I can,for example my all games.when I plugged USB sound card,ipad play sound with 2 seconds delay but when I don't have any sound card iPad can not play sound. Why? @DanielBeck

Comment: This is probably just how the program works. I'd contact Airfoil support and ask them whether there's a solution for your particular situation.

Comment: Thank you very much @DanielBeck, I will wait for your answer.

Comment: @Navid_gh I suggested that you contact their support. I cannot provide any relevant information or answer questions from them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xyzSpeaker.

Make your iPad/iPhone/Android phone or tablet become computer’s speaker:

Function support list:

1. Use your mobile phone as a computer’s Speaker.
2. Use the mobile phone as the microphone input of the computer.
3. Play the sound of the mobile phone through the computer.

Support all operating systems such as Android/iPhone/iPad/MacbookPro/Windows/Linux.

Since the solution uses real-time hardware acceleration, there is no loss of network transmission compression distortion, so the biggest advantage is that there is **no delay and lossless sound quality.** It is suitable for occasions with high delay requirements such as playing games. Plug and play does not require software installation on the computer. . Use the high-quality speakers that come with the iPad Pro, which is better than most low-priced small speakers.

Comment: Hi Jonathan wei! I found your product website here: http://www.xyzspeaker.com/xyzspeaker.html - please include a link in your answer, and steps specific to the current question. One question I have - is AUM really required on the iOS device? Would prefer a cheaper/simpler software option if there is one.